# Sys.WebForms: Error Exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, sys

I have a .NET web that has a form where you can select multiple DropDownLists. One of those, depends on another. It means that if you change the selection of DropDown 1, the content of the DropDown 2 will change. All of this, is requested from a SQL Server Database.

The form works really well when I'm coding and testing, however when I publish the site in another server (not my local machine) it throw this error everytime I change the selection of the DropDown 1, except if I already made use of the form, without touching the DropDown 1 and got some results loaded in the results grid.

I can provide the code if someone needs to see it.

This is the error message:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Like I was thinking, it was something that has to do with the server side. I checked the error with Mozilla Firefox and it said this about the server antivirus:

[image]

Comment: Always go ahead and show the code you are working with and code you have tried. More than likely we will need it to answer your question.

Comment: @Supersnake yes, I know. I was just hoping to get some info about this kind of errors first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you have provided this means it's a client error. The 400 range means the request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled. To know more about this you can visit [**here**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), they list all the status codes and their description. The only issue is we can't know anything more as you haven't provided any more details on your issue. If you want further assistance please provided the code you are working with so we can further help you.

Comment: I've seen that before. Unfortunately it says: **432-499 Unassigned**

Comment: Exactly, it's bad syntax somewhere or another. We have asked for you to post relevant code so we can better assist you. Posting an issue and not providing further details wont get you anywhere. If you can't provided code we are unable to help.

Comment: yes, I know. It's because I'm totally sure about the problem is not about the code. Just needed info about the error code and about people that could have had the same error. I edited my question with the answer.